# StartActivityForResult on a custom ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter

How to do a `startActivityForResult` from a custom `listView`?
Here is my code:

```
((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

and where should I put the `onActivityResult` method?

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
}
```

the list view is displayed in my `MainActivity`, so where I place the method `onActivityResult`? In the `MainActivity` ??

Comment: onActivityResult should be overrided in MainActivity

Comment: onActivityResult method belongs to Activity class . So there is not any possibility to override that function anywhere(RecyclerView Adapter). What seems to be problem here ?

Comment: @RohitSingh Note that Fragments also have an onActivityResult. Their host Activity will forward it to the fragment that called startActivityForResult

Comment: We can override onActivityResult inside a class which extends Fragment class ? or you meant the the callback method which we use by making interface . @RobCo

Comment: Yes, the former. onActivityResult can be overridden in a (support) Fragment subclass. You just have to make sure you also cal startActivityForResult on that Fragment and not on the parent Activity. @RohitSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your activity name MainActivity. Then you should do this

```
((MainActivity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```

And in your MainActivity, override onActivityResult.

```
@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if(requestCode==100){
//do your things
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should override `onActivityResult` in your MainActivity. When second Activity finish, it will be called. Read this linke : https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html?hl=en

```
class MainActivity extends ... {
...
  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
  }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should override onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) in your MainActivity.  If you call adapter from MainActivity with activity context, then you can remove unwanted activity casting.

The adapter code can change to

```
context.startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
```